# Array.prototype.map.call() has a return type of unknown[]

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a function that accepts an array-like object and converts it to an array of numbers. However, TypeScript 3.9.7 does not infer the return type of `Array.prototype.map.call()` - it believes that it returns `unknown[]`.

```js
let input: string[] = ["1", "2", "3"];
// OK
let result1: number[] = input.map(str => Number(str));
// error TS2322: Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'
let result2: number[] = Array.prototype.map.call(input, str => Number(str));
```

I want TypeScript to infer the type of `result2` from that of my callback (`str => Number(str)`). What can I do, **apart from** from using type assertions?

Edit: I am using the `--strict` compiler option.

Comment: It seem working fine on my side, TS v3.9.7, target ES6. `call` always returns `any`, this mean you can cast it to any type.

Comment: @hoangdv I am using the `--strict` option, which is probably the reason your output differs from mine.

Comment: `call` always returns `any` - either you need to use type assertion, or write your own wrapper around that method, or don't use this syntax (do you really need that?) or don't use strict.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `--strict` option, the `call` function will be define as

```
call<T, A extends any[], R>(this: (this: T, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, ...args: A): R;
```

as you can see, `R` now is return type.

For your example, you can set `R` to be `number[]`

```
let result2 = Array.prototype.map.call<string[], any[], number[]>(input, (str: string) => Number(str));
```

Now, `result2` is a `number[]`.

Comment: I was hoping the compiler would infer the return type w/o me explicitly specifying the type parameters. But looks like this is the only viable solution using `Array.prototype map.call()`. By the way, I learned that I could specify a callback as the second argument of `Array.from()`, which *does* correctly infer the return type as I hoped.